# Exception getting JodaTime JSP Taglibs working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jodatime

I'm trying to get the JodaTime taglib working in my Spring 3 MVC app.

Per the [website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-jsptags/) I should be able to put this in my jsp page and it should work.

```
<%@taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("now", new org.joda.time.DateTime()); %>
<joda:format value="${now}" style="SM" />
```

I'm getting this exception however:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/reports/../taglibs.jspf(7,66) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I'm running Glassfish 3.0.1. Servlet version 2.4 is declared in my web.xml file. JSP 2.1. JSTL 1.1.

Addition: 
I've added joda-time-jsptag-1.0.2.jar to my WEB-INF/lib directory. I also have joda-time-1.6.1.jar on the same lib dir.

Does the taglib uri need to be valid? When I try and visit http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags in my browser it redirects to the sourceforge page. Maybe I just need an updated URI link?

Any takers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The taglib URI does not necessarily point to a real web resource. The taglib URI should match the `<uri>` declaration in any of the `.tld` files which is present in the classpath.

Given this fact, there are two possible causes:

1. The TLD file (at least, the JAR file containing it) is not in the classpath at all.
2. The TLD file did declare a different URI.

I don't have experience with JodaTime tags, so I can't tell from top of head if this (mis)behaviour is correct. Best what I can suggest is to extract the JAR file containing the TLD files using some ZIP tool yourself and then read the *actual* `<uri>` in the `.tld` file in the `META-INF` folder of the JAR.

If that turns out to be the same, then you've likely got a problem with the classpath or build settings. Are the JAR files really present in the (expanded) WAR file on the running webapp environment?

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, Servlet 2.4 implies JSP 2.0, not JSP 2.1. Besides, why would you be using Servlet 2.4 instead of 2.5 or even 3.0? Glassfish 3 supports Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked out the TLD file and it was the same. I did a clean/build in NetBeans (IDE) and that fixed it. I don't know why I didn't try that sooner. =) Thanks again. 

As for the mismatch in versions of JSP/Servlet, I probably should spend time getting things in line. This is a long project and that's just what things were.

Comment: If you use Maven, just add this dependency - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time-jsptags